# reading from xml (linq) to windows form

Tags: c#, xml, forms, linq

I made an XML file using linq.(The user fills some textboxes and on submit the data is being added to the xml in this format :

```
<Departments>
   <Department1>
       <Course1 code="x">
          <CourseName></CourseName>
               <CourseCode></CourseCode>
       </Course1>
       <Course2 code="y">
           <CourseName></CourseName>
           <CourseCode></CourseCode>
       </Course2>
   </Department1>
   <Department2>
       <Course3 code="a">
          <CourseName></CourseName>
          <CourseCode></CourseCode>
       </Course3>
    </Department2>
</Departments>
```

Now I want to load the xml to another form and display the data I have in the Xml.
If I have 1 course in department one when I load my form 2textbox should appear(one with the code, one with the name), If I have 2 courses in department1 when I load the form there will be 2 textboxes and 2 other beneath them for the second course(name and code).
But I am not sure since I haven't used c# and xml/ling until recently.

The steps would be I think :

- find out how many  courses I have in department1
- make the textboxes for how many courses I found
- run a query to put the coursecode and coursename in textboxes.

For the form labels/textboxes I thought of using ArrayList

```
          for( int i = 0 ; i = how many courses I have in Departments1 in the xml file)
              {
        coursecode.Add(new TextBox());
        course.Add(new TextBox());
        System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 100 + i * 30);
        (coursecode[i] as TextBox).Location = p;
        (course[i] as TextBox).Location = p;
        (course[i] as TextBox).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
        (course[i] as TextBox).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(coursecode[i] as TextBox);
        this.Controls.Add(coursename[i] as TextBox);
         }
```

But I dont know how to make a linq query and like I said above assign its value to a textboxt or label.

Update: Managed to display it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Regular documentation can help you with this... You can refer to my blog if you want an alternative: http://mazdev.blogspot.ae/2012/04/linq-to-xml.html

Comment: And why are you using `as` with `coursecode[i]` and `coursename[i]` all over the place? Don't use `ArrayList` - use `List<T>` instead. (Also, have a `using` directive for `System.Drawing` so you don't need to qualify it all over the place.)

Answer (score 1):

As Mzn said, the standard documentation should be the place to look. A few methods that you will be using will be `Elements` or `Descendants`, `Count`, and getting the `Value` property for the rest.

A word of caution, since you did not specify in the xml snippet how the data is stored for `<CourseName>` and `<CourseCode>` I assume the worse which is that the values you want are not stored as attributes in which case the `Value` property will return *all* values from that node as well as it's children. If they are attributes, it will be easier as you can use the `Attribute` method to get a `string` for the data.

Once you get the data out, then it's simply create the textboxes, position them, and insert the data into their respective `Text` properties.

A tip: use a `List<T>` instead of an `ArrayList`. The `List<T>` is type safe, so errors from failed casting are eliminated. Also, I found using "dot notation" for LINQ as a good start when learning it as it follows the same conventions as vanilla c# code.

Comment: so It would be better to make the course an element and coursename and coursecode attributes? <course coursename="asa" coursecode="asas" > Right now coursename and coursecode are elements inside of course

Comment: Yes. To give you an example of your setup in the OP, if you were to get the value of a course node with the name and code being as you just provided , the value would be "asaasas".

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? It doesn't use a linq query, but it does get the courses into a `List<>`

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("YourXmlFileNameHere.xml");
        List<XElement> CoursesInDepartment1;

        // Step 1
        CoursesInDepartment1 = doc.Element("Departments").Element("Department1").Elements().ToList();

        // Step 2
        foreach (XElement elem in CoursesInDepartment1) {
            TextBox nameBox = new TextBox();
            TextBox codeBox = new TextBox();
            //Set the location, size, ect.

            //Step 3
            nameBox.Text = elem.Element("CourseName").Value;
            codeBox.Text = elem.Element("CourseCode").Value;

            this.Controls.Add(nameBox.Text);
            this.Controls.Add(codeBox.Text);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope this helps!